# any way to route all the requests to a method before they are redirected to the correct ones in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to see if there's a way to pre-check all the requests before they are routed to the correct method? 
all of my requests would have version# in param. it would be really helpful to check that at first place and decide whether the client needs to upgrade or not. it is a bit painful to check in all the methods, so I was wondering if there's a way to 'filter' the request at first. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is called a *Filter*.

See [The Essentials of Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)

**Example**

```
@WebFilter( urlPatterns = "/*" ) // Filter all URLs
public class VersionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter( ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Do your filtering here

    }

    @Override
    public void init( FilterConfig filterConfig ) throws ServletException { ... }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { ... }
}
```